# KAfka cross cluster group id

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have the same Kafka group Id, but used in different Kafka clusters can that same group id work across clusters.  This is the group id for Kafka consumers.

If I have the same microservice consuming off the same topic in two different Kafka clusters also in two different datacenters will the consumer group Ids take effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are also sharing a `__consumer_offsets` topic between distinct clusters (not reasonably possible without maybe a MirrorMaker), no it'll not take effect.

Comment: OK, so are you saying if I use mirrormaker and I share the __consumer_offsets topic between then this is possible?

Comment: Maybe, but I wouldn't recommend it or have tested it. Because your consumers probably should not be shared across clusters.